# How can I allow other applications to access API from my application in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an application in Spring and I want other applications to be able to send data to my application server. I am new to Spring and I don't know how to allow other applications to get/send data to the server through GET/POST request. What changes do I have to make in my Spring Security File.

This is part of my code in Spring security XML file

```
...
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" /> 
        <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
...
```

This is my API in the controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/newBoook")
public ResponseEntity<?> saveLicense(HttpSession session, @RequestBody HashMap<String, JSONObject> bookDetails) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
    if (serviceBookManagement.saveBookDetails(bookDetails)) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Book has been successfully entered!");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new String("Sorry, there was an error while trying to process the request."));
}
```

Comment: The process of exposing your application depends mainly on what you want to do and your architecture. Are you talking about the differents steps you need to do this?

Comment: @HarryCoder Yes, since I am new to Spring, I have no Idea how to begin with this

Comment: By default, Spring Security comes with CSRF enabled, your clients have to send a CSRF token in order to make unsafe requests. See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy your API on a Web Server and there are many cases and steps to follow.

1. Use a Web Server such as [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) : in an embedded mode (a `jar` file) or a [server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) mode (a `war` file).
2. You can deploy your application in a local network or on a [cloud provider](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) to expose your API.
3. Your API have to be [secure](https://medium.com/swlh/3-ways-to-secure-your-web-api-for-different-situations-8d5cd4762ab3) also, to avoid your API to be hacked.

There are many aspects you will have to manage, but I think, this is a good beginning.